# Are the $\lambda_I$-Calculus and the $\lambda_K$-Calculus equivalent?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I see here and there mention of the $\lambda_I$-Calculus (in which every variable must be used at least once) and the $\lambda_K$-Calculus (in which a variable can also be unused).  Are they equivalent?  Why has the latter kinda obscured the former?

*EDIT*

By *equivalent*, I mean they have the same expressive power, namely, being *universal* or *Turing complete*.

Comment: Do you have references, to make the question more self-contained?

Comment: Might help to be more precise about what "equivalent" means here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've basically answered the question yourself.

$\lambda K$ is just another name for the standard, untyped lambda calculus.

$\lambda I$ is a strict subset of $\lambda K$.

$\lambda I$ doesn't allow terms where one abstracts over a variable but doesn't use it. So
$$K = \lambda xy.x \in \lambda K$$
but
$$ K \not\in \lambda I$$

Thanks to this restriction, $\lambda I$ has some interesting properties, in particular if $M$ has a normal form then so do all its sub-terms.

[Barendregt, H. P. The Lambda Calculus: Its Syntax and Semantics](http://mathgate.info/cebrown/notes/barendregt.php) contains some notes about $\lambda I$, namely:

> ... the $\lambda I$ calculus is sufficient to define all recursive functions  (since $K_1 := \lambda xy . yIIx$ satisfies $K_1xc_n = x$ for each of Church's numerals $c_n := \lambda fz . f^n z$ - it is also the case that for each finite set $n$ of nf's, we can find a "local $K$ for $n$" $K_n$ such that $K_nMN = M$ for each $N$ in $n$).
>
> ... The $\lambda I$ calculus corresponds to the combinatory logic with primitive combinators $I$, $B$, $C$, and $S$. ...

Comment: Since the term *recursive* is abused, does he mean $\lambda_I$ is universal?

Comment: @plmday I'm not sure what you mean by universal. I extended the citation a bit. The statement means that in $\lambda I$ one can express all [$\mu$-recursive functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-recursive_function). This means that any Turing machine can be simulated in $\lambda I$ (and of course in $\lambda K$ as well). See also [Church-Turing thesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis).

Comment: In [To mock a mockingbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Mock_a_Mockingbird) the author claims that _Neither theory can be said to be "better" than the other; each has applications which the other does not_. Was he wrong? (I've asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4164233/doesnt-lambda-k-calculus-include-lambda-i-calculus), but haven't got a satisfying answer.)

Answer (score 5):

I don't have much to add to the other answers, except that for **termination behavior**, it is sufficient to consider only the $\lambda_I$ version: see e.g. [Strong Normalization from Weak Normalization by Translation into the Lambda-I-Calculus](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1025693307470) by Gortz, Reuss and Sorensen.

Answer (score 0):

In effect, intuitively, by definition later one includes former one as a subset.
Also observe that in the real world, unused variables are norm, unless compiler catches it up.
Does that answer some part of your query?